# how to optimise matlab plot from serial port

Tags: matlab

I am having trouble getting data to plot from a serial port. The data being sent is split in 3 bytes which when combined represent an adc value read from a microcontroller followed by a 4th representing the unit. Sometimes the data is out of sync with how it is sent and the plot is also very slow to update. The fourth value should only ever be 10,11 or 12 but when i check the data received sometimes this is not the case. how could i check that the data received is valid before i display it most optimally? also are there any optimizations i could make to the code that would make the changes in transmitted data output faster to the figure? I have taken out all the serial port setup for this code snippet.

```
clear all;
delete(instrfindall);
clear;
close all;
clc;

 s = serial('COM4'); %assigns the object s to serial port

set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 1); %number of bytes in inout buffer
set(s, 'FlowControl', 'hardware');
set(s, 'BaudRate', 9600);
set(s, 'Parity', 'none');
set(s, 'DataBits', 8);
set(s, 'StopBit', 1);
set(s, 'Timeout',10);

disp(get(s,'Name'));
prop(1)=(get(s,'BaudRate'));
prop(2)=(get(s,'DataBits'));
prop(3)=(get(s, 'StopBit'));
prop(4)=(get(s, 'InputBufferSize'));

disp(['Port Setup Done!!',num2str(prop)]);

fopen(s);          

data = [];
dataRecieved = zeros(2000);

h = figure; %Start figure before loop

axis auto;
grid on;
t = 1;

while isgraphics(h,'figure')

 for x = 1:4 %%% loop and store 4 values        
    a(x) = fread(s); %reads 4 values of the data from the serial port and stores it to the matrix a
 end

if(a(4) == 10)
    data(t) = ((a(1)-96)*10)+(a(2)-80)+((a(3)-32)/10); %Update current value of data
    plot(data(max(1,t-250):t),'-r'); %%%Plot the most recent 250 values
    xlabel('Time'); % Create xlabel
    ylabel('Voltage in V'); % Create ylabel
    title('Real Time Data of Voltage'); % Create title

elseif(a(4) == 11)
    data(t) = ((a(1)-112)*10)+(a(2)-64)+((a(3)-32)/10); %Update current value of data
    plot(data(max(1,t-250):t),'-r'); %%%Plot the most recent 250 values
    xlabel('Time'); % Create xlabel
    ylabel('Voltage in V'); % Create ylabel
title('Real Time Data of Current'); % Create title


elseif(a(4) == 12)
    data(t) = ((a(1)-96)*10)+(a(2)-64)+((a(3)-32)/10); %Update current value of data
    plot(data(max(1,t-250):t),'-r'); %%%Plot the most recent 100 values
    xlabel('Time'); % Create xlabel
    ylabel('Voltage in V'); % Create ylabel
    title('Real Time Data of Power'); % Create title

end

drawnow;

disp([num2str(t),'th value is',num2str(data(t))]);

t = t + 1;

end
```

Comment: how many of those data units are send per second? also could you elaborate a little on what `s` is? how do you set it up?

Comment: s is the serial input to the pc from a micro controller's uart transmit. the baudrate is 9600 and i have added the aditional code you asked for

Answer (score 0):

just a few thoughts as you dont have a real error in your code. How often do you want your plot to be updated? yes of course it should be somewhat realtimey but wouldn't be every second enough? i feel like your code is just running in loops and sometimes something arrives.

For your code: i feel like you are dealing with 3 cases (and maybe others will come up) thats why i would use a `switch`. Also lines like `xlabel('Time');` are in all cases so i would but them somewhere else in the loop. ALSO you dont have to rename the axes in every loop once in the beginning is enough.

How often does the type switch? i feel like your code is based on the assumption that it does basically every other time. doenst you start the code and get the same unit until you close the window? then you wouldnt need the if in the loop but just after the start up for the first time and then jsut plot with regards to that unit